# crud ajax jquery symfony3 wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

**Problem:** How do I validate the form and return the validation messages in modal box without refreshing the page.

I just started learning Symfony 3 and I got trouble adding data using AJAX.
I know how to include the template form inside of the modal box but I don't know how to show the error messages of $form->isValid() inside the modal and persist it.

**new.html.twig**

UPDATE: I can now call the method action in Controller. But when I validate the form I haven't received any validation error inside modal box.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.withdropdown').dropdown();
        $('.add-company-launch').modal();

        $('#company-form').submit(function(e) {

            var formUrl = "{{ path('monteal_backend_company_ajax') }}";
            var formData = new FormData(this)

            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data:  formData,
                 contentType: false,
                 cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data['status'] === 'success'){
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        $('#add-company').html(data['html']);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    })
</script>
```

{% endblock %}

CompanyController.php

UPDATE: I have create two methods for AJAX,
1. Method to handle a form.
2. AjaxHandler.

```
   public function newAction() {

        $company = new Company();

        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, $company);

        return $this->render('Admin/Backend/Company/new.html.twig', array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
    }

    public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {

        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'You can access this only using Ajax!'), 400);
        }

        $company = new Company();
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, $company);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($company);
            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'status' => 'success'), 200
            );
        }

        $html = $this->renderView("Admin/Backend/Company/new.html.twig", array(
            'form' => $form->createView())
        );

        return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'error', 'html' => $html]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - In your newAction, just create the form and pass the view (createView) to your template.

2 - write a ajaxFormHandlerAction and here create the form, handle it, validate it, render a view in a variable :
$html = $this->renderView('yourTemplate.html.twig', array($form->createView()));
Edit: of course your ajax must post the form to your newly ajax url... END Edit

3 - if it is'nt validated 
Return a JsonResponse(array('html' => $html, 'status' => 'error'));
    if validated
Return a JsonResponse(array('status' => 'success'));

4 - In your ajax success callback, render the newly form if status error..
    if status success, redirect or whatever

Hope this help

Edit :

something like this for your controler :

```
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
    public function ajaxFormHandlerAction(Request $request) 
    {
        $company = getYourCompany(); //get it from db?
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, $company));
        $form ->handleRequest($request);
        if($form ->isValid()){
             //do whatever you want, maybe persist, flush()
             return new JsonResponse(array(
                'status' => 'success'));
        }
        $html = $this->renderView("yourModalTemplate.html.twig", array('form' => $form->createView()));
        return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'error', 'html' => $html]);
     }
```

And in your success ajax callback:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    if(data['status'] === 'success'){
        alert('success');
        // maybe redirect the user ???
    }else if(data['status' === 'error']){
        $('#idOfYourModal').html(data['html']); //assuming you use jquery, or translate to javascript
    }
},
```

You have to create a twig template with only the modal inside...

Comment: I have update my question, as well the form handler and ajax handler, as of now, I do not know how to handle the ajax request and response. Could you please check my source code above. Thank you

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, one more question, why I don't get any error response from controller to twig? I update my code above. thank you

Comment: Not sure to understand your question... In fact, the ajax form handler will create your form, isValid() will place errors in your form (in case of an error of course), and the renderView will create a view with the errors in it. With javascript, you just remove the 'old' form, and show the new one with errors in it.

Comment: Okay, first, can you explain why should I put a condition on success function? ` if(data['status'] === 'success'){ alert('success'); } else { $('#add-company').html(data['html']); }` where its clear that if the form is valid everything are all well.

Comment: secondly, why you didn't put any alert message in `error: funcition`, where its clear that the user must see the error messages when using the form?

Comment: Lastly, about the form validation messages, I still don't know too, why the error message won't show in the modal box. But if I test using the plain php (without modal) it works.

Comment: for the first question even if the form is not correctly filled, the ajax query is  correctly done.
Edit : so in both case (form un/correctly filled) ajax come with a success (200 ok). To discriminate whether or not the form is correctly filled, you use the status parameter that you send from your controller .

If for some reason your server does'nt reply, or for some reason gives a error 500, the error callback will take place...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139837/discussion-between-constantin-and-phpmeter).